# ML Model on BigQuery Aborts due to Max Session Time Limit

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to create a BQ ML Model that Aborts pre-maturely due to the Max Session Time Limit constraint of 30 minutes on the Project I'm executing under.

Is there some way to create this Model in chunks/sections so that it doesn't abort due to time constraints? Either by reducing the number of columns selected (460 columns) or the numbers of rows (~1 Million) or tweak any parameters in the OPTIONS section?

These are the OPTIONS I'm selecting while creating the Model:

```
model_type = 'BOOSTED_TREE_CLASSIFIER',
data_split_method = 'SEQ',
data_split_eval_fraction = 0.2,
data_split_col = 'DATE_COL',

booster_type = 'GBTREE',
max_iterations = 50, 
early_stop = false,
subsample = 0.8,
MIN_TREE_CHILD_WEIGHT = 1000,
COLSAMPLE_BYTREE = 0.3,
MAX_TREE_DEPTH = 6,
SUBSAMPLE = 0.7,

input_label_cols = ['COLx']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce the number of columns/rows selected, increase max iterations, reduce subsample, increase min tree child weight, use a different data split method like random instead of seq

Answer (score -1):

Before that, have you tried to exclude some columns from your input data? This can be done in SQL by using the except() command or you can simply only include the features you care about.

```
SELECT * EXCEPT



WITH orders AS
  (SELECT 5 as order_id,
  "sprocket" as item_name,
  200 as quantity)
SELECT * EXCEPT (order_id)
FROM orders;

/*-----------+----------*
 | item_name | quantity |
 +-----------+----------+
 | sprocket  | 200      |
 *-----------+----------*/
```

Trying to tune down the max_tree_depth or using early stop might also help.